# Rendering to Oculus Rift from Python

Tags: python, c, animation, blender, virtual-reality

I've been interested in creating an add-on for Blender(an animation software) that would allow animation with the Oculus Rift.

The Oculus Rift SDK operates with C, but Blender operates with Python, which brings me to my question:

How can I realistically hope to communicate between the two?

If this question is too vague, please let me know.

Comment: [This article](https://code.blender.org/2015/03/1451/) might interest you. The multiview support discussed is now part of the current release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't written anything in Blender, but if the python works the same as usual you can extend it with c libraries.

So you could create a c module to work with the Oculus Rift and call it from Python.

Try this link and see if it helps: [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)